# Simple two column layout with fixed sidebar and fluid content

Tags: html, css

I have seen a lot of tutorials which create a two column layout with a fixed sidebar on the left and fluid content on the right. They also have full height sidebars, that is, the sidebar goes down to the height of the main content window. Something like this site:

http://robertgreiner.com/

However, a lot of these seem to be designed to work with IE6. Here is one such example:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-left-frame-layout/

If I want to drop support for IE6, is there a hack-free way of achieving it. For example, if my target was IE8+, can I implement this a simpler and cleaner way?

Comment: Yes you can implement it a simpler way if you don't need to support IE6. Just drop all code from the example which is supporting IE6.

Comment: Hey there.  I used the Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework on my site.  The side bar you are referencing is built in.  Shoot me an email if you need any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think you want:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    Some content
</div>
<div id="content">
    Main content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    width:20%;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:fixed;
}
#content {
    margin-left:22%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:1500px;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/UVAjB/)**